# decode following urls in python

Tags: python, decode, encode

I have a URL like this:

```
http://idebate.org/debatabase/debates/constitutional-governance/house-supports-dalai-lama%E2%80%99s-%E2%80%98third-way%E2%80%99-tibet
```

Then I used following script in python to decode this url:

```
full_href = urllib.unquote(full_href.encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')
```

However, i got error like this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 89: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when trying to write in file

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  The `urllib.unquote` looks like Python 2.<something>, but I get no error when I run this in CPython 2.6.  Are you sure the error isn't pointing to some other line?  (`print`ing that Unicode string to an ASCII-only terminal or pipe, for example, might produce an error like you're seeing.)  Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Also, please post the code that's _actually producing the error_ --- when you write to a file.  I suspect you're trying to write your Unicode string to an ASCII-only output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @KevinJ.Chase pointed out, you were most likely trying to write to a file with string in incompatible ascii format.
You can either change your write file encoding, or encode your `full_href` to `ascii`, something like this:

```
# don't decode again to utf-8
full_href = urllib.unquote(url.encode('ascii'))
... then write to your file stream
```

or,

```
...
# encode your your to compatible encoding on write, ie. utf-8
with open('yourfilenamehere', 'w') as f:
    f.write(full_href.encode('utf-8'))
```